# Angular 5 Material: Make mat-radio-group required in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

Trying to make my radio button group required but have failed to find anything concrete on how to do so.  Here is my html code and ts:

```
<mat-radio-group name="dealtype" [(ngModel)]="formType" formControlName="formType" required>
          <mat-radio-button value="New Lease">New Lease</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="Ground Lease-New">Ground Lease-New</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>


this.newLeaseForm = new FormGroup({
  'emailGroup': new FormControl({ value: this.selectedToAdd }),
  'emailList': new FormControl({ value: this.selectedToRemove }),
  'remarks': new FormControl({ value: this.remarks }),
  ['myControl']: new FormControl({ value: this.selectedBU.BusinessUnitId }, Validators.required),
  'formType': new FormControl(null, Validators.requiredTrue),
```

Comment: Hi,Experiencing the same problem and searching for a solution. I will post back if I find one.

Comment: Same here with Angular 7. Seriously Angular Material team?